# To Copy the Selected text in Pdf which is inside an Iframe without using copy, paste

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdf

How to copy the selected text from a pdf which is inside an iframe using double click or any event.[image]
This is my application If i double click on a word it should be copied in the text field on the rightside,
Actually i have done it on a text File But For Pdf i couldnt do it. Any Idea or help will be appreciated,Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the PDF displayed in that iframe? Using the Adobe Reader plugin? Using pdf.js? In the former case forget it, cf. @NickC's answer. In the latter, pdf.js gurus might know a way.

Answer (score 0):

The adobe documentation says there's no way for JavaScript in the browser to access the PDF.

> Acrobat JavaScript does not have access to objects within an HTML
>   page. Similarly,  HTML JavaScript cannot access objects within a PDF
>   file.

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/javascript/AcroJSGuide.pdf

What you could try is rendering the pdf itself in JavaScript using a library like [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). Once the pdf is part of the dom, you could attach a listener in a similar fashion to what you've done for the text documents.